# json parser not return all row of data.only first row is return

Tags: php, android, json

My PHP web service returns multiple records, my problem is how I can parse it in Android?

```
    <?php
      //load and connect to MySQL database stuff
      include('../includes/include.inc.php');     
    ?>      

    <?     ############################################################################################# ?>
    <? 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

      $query = "SELECT book_log.`issue_date`,book_log.`due_date`,book_log.`status`,employees.`first_name`,employees.`middle_name`,employees.`last_name`,books.`title` from book_log inner join employees on book_log.`librarian_id`=employees.`id` inner join books on book_log.`book_id`=books.`id` where book_log.`user_id`=(select id from users where username='".$_POST['username']."')";

      $info=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

      if(mysql_num_rows($info)>0)
      {
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($info))
         {
            $response["issue_date"]=$row['issue_date'];
            $response["due_date"]=$row['due_date'];
            $response["status"]=$row['status'];       
            $response["first_name"]=$row['first_name'];
            $response["middle_name"]=$row['middle_name'];
            $response["last_name"]=$row['last_name'];
            $response["title"]=$row['title'];
            $json=json_encode($response);
            print_r($json);     
         }
       } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid Student_Id!";
            die(json_encode($response));
       }    
    }

    ?>

    <form action="#" method="post">
      Username:<br />
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
      <br />
      <br />
      Password:<br />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

I have created a parser but the web service return only one row.

> ## my json parser is
>
> it return only last record,
>       how can recieve all other records,

```
package com.clockerp.connection;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
               // Log.e("HTTP RESPONSE", " result " + is.toString());

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 10);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

> ### json respnce is

```
03-27 11:12:56.088: E/himanshu(1394): checking
03-27 11:12:56.336: E/himanshu(1394): http://192.168.1.148/clock/webservice/student_libraray_info.php
03-27 11:12:56.337: E/request!(1394): starting
03-27 11:12:57.739: E/HTTP RESPONSE 1is(1394):  result org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@2ca38b98
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):  result 
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394): {"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Business Statistics"}{"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Marketing Research"}
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394): <form action="#" method="post">
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   Username:<br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   Password:<br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394):   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE2 sb(1394): </form>
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):  result 
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394): {"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Business Statistics"}{"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Marketing Research"}
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394): <form action="#" method="post">
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   Username:<br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   Password:<br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <br />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394):   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
03-27 11:12:57.742: E/HTTP RESPONSE 3 json(1394): </form>
03-27 11:12:57.743: E/HTTP RESPONSE 4 jobj(1394):  result {"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Business Statistics"}
03-27 11:12:57.744: E/json response(1394): {"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Business Statistics"}
```

> when i am converting json String into json object then it save only first row.other row are not come.

Comment: Try to return only json objects instead of http response.

Comment: try to save the record in an array and echo it after the while loop..

Answer (score 0):

return json object for example object:

```
$obj = "[";

whille(mysqli_fetch_array($run$query)){

 if($obj!="["){ $obj.="," }

 $obj.='{"first_name":"'.$row[1].'",';
 $obj.='"second_name":"'.$row[2].'"}';

   }

 $obj.="]";
 return json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: Now i am facing this prob in my json parsar class 03-27 14:27:12.619: E/JSON Parser(1372): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Business Statistics"},{"issue_date":"2015-03-19","due_date":"2015-04-03","status":"Issued","first_name":"Admin","middle_name":"","last_name":"User","title":"Marketing Research"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to manually parse the SQL response, you can simply have PHP handle it. This way you will get a valid JSON response with all the rows as an JSON array.

```
$query = "SELECT ...";
$rows = mysql_query($query);
print json_encode($rows);
```

Then on the Android side, you parse this as JSON array instead of object. You do not need to parse it manually, but just pass the whole HTTP response to JSONArray:

```
JSONArray rows = new JSONArray( response );
for ( int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++ ) {
    JSONObject obe = rows.getJSONObject( i );
}
```

You may get trouble if the response contains also HTML tags, which I really would avoid and only return the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

try to save the record in an aray and then echo it outside the while loop. your problem here is that you save every row in the same variable so thats why it returns the
last row.

```
 $data=array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($info)>0)
          {
             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($info))
             {


            $response["issue_date"]=$row['issue_date'];
                $response["due_date"]=$row['due_date'];
            $response["status"]=$row['status'];

            $response["first_name"]=$row['first_name'];
            $response["middle_name"]=$row['middle_name'];
            $response["last_name"]=$row['last_name'];

            $response["title"]=$row['title'];
           $data[]=$response;
           }
        $json=array('data'=>$data);
        echo json_encode($data);

          }
```